# How to exclude files matching two distinct wildcards in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-line, wildcard

I have a folder containing file format for example

```
20140821160438_708_IP_JUL_2014.csv
20140821160438_708_PUD_JUL_2014.csv
20140821160438_708_IP_GP_JUL_2014.csv
20140821160438_708_PUD_GP_JUL_2014.csv
```

I want to grab file without `GP` in the file name and grab file of only `IP` and `PUD`. For example, I want to grab only `IP` in the file name, How do I write 2 condition in the following code to exclude `PUD` and `PUD_GP`?

```
FOR /R "C:\Share\PRC Interface" %%G IN (! *PUD_GP*.csv) DO move "%%G" C:\ERP_Interface\PRCERP\IP
```

Comment: How is this related to WinSCP? How is this related to programming? Please ask on [su].

Comment: the scritp is in the batch file of the winscp thanks.

Comment: WinSCP does not have `FOR`, nor `move` commands (it has `mv` though). WinSCP cannot move local files. So this is not a WinSCP script. It rather looks like a Windows batch command. The only reasonably close task WinSCP can do is to move files matching your rules from a remote directory to a local one or vice versa. Is this what you want to do? Or do you actually want to modify that Windows command to move only matching LOCAL files to another local directory (what has nothing to do with WinSCP)? Please make your question clear. Do not try to suggests tools to use, rather describe the problem.

Comment: the script is in a .bat file, and it will call the winscp.exe, the for script is inside the batch file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pushd "C:\Share\PRC Interface"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
    dir /a-d /b /s *_IP_*.csv *_PUD_*.csv ^| find /i /v "_GP_"
') do echo move "%%~fa" "C:\ERP_Interface\PRCERP\IP"
popd
```

Retrieve the list of all the required files and filter to exclude those not wanted

`move` operation is only echoed to console. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` command